# Java new Keylistener after changing JPanel doesn't work

Tags: java, keylistener

for my game I'm coding for school I have the following problem:

When the game starts, it does load a JPanel into the frame with some intro stuff. To switch between some images, I've added a simple keylistener. After everything is done there, it does remove everything from the contentpane and loads the first level. These lines are doing it for me:

```
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new level1());
    frame.getContentPane().validate();
```

Now, my first level is loaded successfully, but the keylistener is broken. In my public level1() I've defined a new KeyListener, but it doesn't respond to my inputs. The KeyListener is fully working if I don't switch the JPanel. The relevant code for reloading the new KeyListener is:

```
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
    keylistener = new AL();
    addKeyListener(keylistener);
```

Everything is working fine, e.g. enemys are moving. But the KeyListener doesn't do anything.

edit: both keylisteners are completely different

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Somewhy the JPanel fails to get Focus. With my update method I know make sure at every tick, that my JPanel is focused. This solved it, but I don't get why a single focus request isn't enough.

Comment: The `requestFocusInWindow()` method only works when the method is invoked on a component being displayed in a visible window. Don't use a KeyListener. The better solution is to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: I know that Key Bindings is the better way, but this was just a quick game for school, so i didn't care. Logically, first the JPanel was loaded into the frame and after that, the focus was set. Maybe it was still too early, but thanks for your answer.